# Workmanager Worker class doWork() method not being called

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

`doWork()` method of worker class never called in Android

I want to sync the offline data with the server when the internet connection will be connected

//Worker Manager  Class

```
class UploadWorker (context: Context, workerParameters: WorkerParameters, val authRepository: AuthRepository): Worker(context,workerParameters) {
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        Log.e("inDo", "work")
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val resource = authRepository.loginAsync("wmwdwnd@gmail.com", "sdnwnd").await()
            when (resource) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    Result.success()
                    Log.e("complete", "ass")
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    Result.success()
                    Log.e("error", "asdd")
                    //when (resource.code) {}
                }
                else -> {
                    Result.success()
                }
            }
        }
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

// View Class

```
class WorkMnagerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_work_mnager)
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build()
            val data = Data.Builder()
                .putString("tittle", "")
                .build()
            val oneTimeWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(UploadWorker::class.java)
                .setInputData(data)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .build()


            WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(oneTimeWorkRequest);
            WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(oneTimeWorkRequest.id)
                .observe(this, Observer {
                    it?.let {
                        if (it.state == WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED) {
                            // Show the work state in text view
                            Log.e("ddd","Download enqueued.")
                        } else if (it.state == WorkInfo.State.BLOCKED) {
                            Log.e("ddd","Download blocked")
                        } else  {
                            Log.e("ddd","Download running.")
                        }
                    }
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is the log `Log.e("inDo", "work")` is getting printed

Comment: @ManojPerumarath sir nothing is printed in Log.e(), even debugger is also not working

Comment: Try to remove `val authRepository: AuthRepository` parameter from constructor.

Comment: @J.D.1731 yes it going in doWork method but i want to   post the data to the server in this method . i am using the MVVM pattern i need  authRespository class to  implement the web services

Comment: Use any other way to provide the dependency, the constructor has to be without any additional parameters. 
If you are using any DI libs, then unfortunately you will end up with providing Factory for your Worker, ref:
https://android.jlelse.eu/injecting-into-workers-android-workmanager-and-dagger-948193c17684

Comment: @J.D.1731 thanks to guide me .  i have used KoiComponent interface to call Api in do Work Class

Comment: Out of curiosity, has it started working fine?

Comment: @J.D.1731  yes it working fine

Answer (score 2):

A `worker` class only support synchronous tasks (WorkManager takes care of launching `doWork()` on a background executor. From [Threading in Worker](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/worker.html):

> Note that Worker.doWork() is a synchronous call - you are expected to do the entirety of your background work in a blocking fashion and finish it by the time the method exits.

If you need to run something asynchronous, I suggest that you use or a `CoroutineWorker` or a `ListenableWorker`.

You can find more information on the [Threading in WorkManager guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/threading).

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you're connected to network, since you've added a constraint

```
.setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
```

Also try checking the network, you can check this using

```
val cm = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
val activeNetwork: NetworkInfo? = cm.activeNetworkInfo
val isConnected: Boolean = activeNetwork?.isConnected == true
```

At last you've added your task as an asynchronous, `WorkManager` works synchronously, try changing that also.

Answer (score 0):

`Workers` classes has to have only two parameters in the constructor
`context: Context` and `workerParameters: WorkerParameters`

```
class UploadWorker (context: Context, workerParameters: WorkerParameters) {..}
```

In your case, there is one another `val authRepository: AuthRepository` which breaks your code. 
To pass additional dependencies to your `Worker` you can use `WorkerFactory`, described in details [here](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/muselee-work-manager-part-2/)